# Why does liquid rise to same level in these different capillaries?

Tags: forces, surface-tension, capillary-action

I'm having a doubt in the two types of approaches used to calculate the liquid rise in capillaries- one by the excess pressure method and the other by balancing weight of fluid column by the forces due to surface tension.
the liquid in case (B) rises up an initially conical and then straight capillary.when the liquid reaches in the straight part , the pressure at the points indicated is same in both diagrams since the straight parts of both capillary are identical. With this approach the height rise will be same in both cases . Now by the other approach approach is by balancing the forces by surface tension and the weight of liquid the weight in second case is more but the force by surface tension are same due to identical meniscuses so how can liquid rise to same level ?
what am I getting wrong,
sorry for the long question [image]